# Faster way to replace bunch of strings by regexp in huge text in Swift

Tags: swift, regex, string, replace

I noticed that `String.replacingOccurrences` works too slow.

```swift
content = content.replacingOccurrences(of: lookup, with: replace)
```

I wonder if anyone know better solution for this problem in Swift?
Maybe some frameworks or methods for fast in-place replace?

Full function code:

```swift
/// Replacing content of each file by regex criteria in selected folder.
private func replaceContent(occurrences: [(lookup: String, replace: String)],
                            inFilesByRegEx fileRegEx: String,
                            folder: Folder) throws {
    let regex = try RegEx(pattern: fileRegEx)
    for file in folder.files.recursive where regex.test(file.path) {
        var content = try file.readAsString()
        for (lookup, replace) in occurrences {
            content = content.replacingOccurrences(of: lookup, with: replace)
        }
        try file.write(content)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the easiest solution I've finally found:

```swift
private func replace(_ lookup: String,
                     with replace: String,
                     inFilesByRegEx fileRegEx: String,
                     folder: Folder) throws {
    let regex = try RegEx(pattern: fileRegEx)
    for file in folder.files.recursive where regex.test(file.path) {
        var content = try file.readAsString()
        content = content.replacingOccurrences(of: lookup, with: replace, options: .regularExpression)
        try file.write(content)
    }
}
```

I just use complex regular expression which combine all lookup strings and then do it in one pass for each file.

Comment: Your original version could end up making many passes through each file-- once per every entry in `occurrences`. This version makes only one pass through the file, which accounts for the difference.

Comment: @TomHarrington Yeah, you are right! I didn't get it in my first naive solution.